# C# How can JObject.Parse() wait until it gets json string totally

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, async-await

I just create simple JsonDataManager to get writing in a JSON format and parsing it to use it later however `JObject.Parse` doesn't wait until webclient gets JSON data and directly use "its going to be filled by JSON" string.  How can I push it to wait until it gets JSON string totally?

```
public class JsonDataManager{

         String myData = "its going to be filled by json";


        public JsonDataManager(string Category)
        {
            String url = "<a href="http://www.kaanbarisbayrak.com/?json=get_category_posts&cat="+Category;<br">http://www.kaanbarisbayrak.com/?json=get_category_posts&cat="+Catego...</a> />
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            wc.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url), UriKind.Relative);
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);

        }


        public String getWriting()
        {
            JObject obj = JObject.Parse(myData);
            JArray array = (JArray)obj["posts"];
            string writing = (string)array[0]["content"]; 
            return writing;
        }



        private void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            myData = e.Result;
        }


    }
```

Comment: How/when is getWriting() being called?  Also, it looks like you are adding the completed event handler *after* you make the async call.

Comment: i am calling it with first creating the object passing the category id and then just show it in messagebox to test it whether it comes up MessageBox.Show(manager.getWriting());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use a `Task<string>`. This means `getWriting()` is a function that will *eventually* return a string but won't block the thread. To do this just wrap your download call in a task. You can then attach a `ContinueWith` function which serves as your callback which receives the result and prints it to the screen.

```
class JsonDataManager
{
    String url = "http://www.kaanbarisbayrak.com/?json=get_category_posts&cat=";
    string data = "";
    HttpClient hc;

    public JsonDataManager(string Category)
    {
        hc = new HttpClient();
        url += Category;
    }

    public Task<string> getWriting()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() =>
        {
            data = hc.GetStringAsync(url).Result;

            // use the resulting string
            JObject obj = JObject.Parse(data);
            JArray array = (JArray)obj["posts"];
            string writing = (string)array[0]["content"];
            return writing;
        });
    }
}
```

---

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        JsonDataManager manager = new JsonDataManager("4");
        manager.getWriting().ContinueWith((task) =>
        {
            string writing = task.Result;
            MessageBox.Show(writing);
        });
    }
```

Comment: wc.DownloadString is not defined in windows phone so that i have to use DownloadStringAsync and it requires me to do same things that i have done so far(like DownloadStringCompleted and so on)

Comment: @KBB Which version of .NET are you using? It looks like it is supported in the latest versions for windows phone, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx. The problem with completed callbacks is they turn your code inside-out and it loses its natural flow. This is why tasks were introducted in .NET 4.0. `HttpClient.GetStringAsync()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551745.ASPx would be better because you don't have to wrap it in a Task yourself, it already returns a task.

Comment: Well you are right however i tried in a different ways but it always stucks in myData.Result; it blocks the main thread

Comment: Does it get stuck permanently or just blocks the thread while it is downloading the string? Because `getWriting()` could also return `Task<string>` if you do not want it to block and let the calling function decide when to stop and wait for the result.

Comment: I change it in that way and now it stucks at data = await hc.GetStringAsync(url) you can get the file [link](http://kaanbarisbayrak.com/test.txt)

Comment: The problem with the link you posted is that you are calling `.Result` on the UI thread and this causes a deadlock. Instead you want to use `ContinueWith` which allows the Task to run asynchronously (keeping the UI thread free) and when it completes it prints out the result. No blocking or locking, pure async responsiveness. I have updated my answer to show you how this looks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait until the WebClient has completed the download.
One way is to use a ManualResetEvent:

```
public class JsonDataManager
{
   String myData = "its going to be filled by json";
   ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

   public JsonDataManager(string Category)
   {
       String url = "<a href="http://www.kaanbarisbayrak.com/?json=get_category_posts&cat="+Category;<br">http://www.kaanbarisbayrak.com/?json=get_category_posts&cat="+Catego...</a> />
       WebClient wc = new WebClient();
       wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
       wc.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
       wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url), UriKind.Relative);
       wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
   }

   public String getWriting()
   {
       mre.WaitOne();
       JObject obj = JObject.Parse(myData);
       JArray array = (JArray)obj["posts"];
       string writing = (string)array[0]["content"]; 
       return writing;
   }

   private void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
       myData = e.Result;
       mre.Set();
   }
}
```

Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) about reset event.

Comment: Well it just stucks at mre.WaitOne() when i call getWriting() in a different class

Answer (score 0):

```
public class JsonDataManager
{
    readonly String _url;

    public JsonDataManager(string category)
    {
        _url = @"http://www.kaanbarisbayrak.com/?json=get_category_posts&cat="+category;
    }

    public async Task<String> getWriting()
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        wc.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";

        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsnync(_url));
        JArray array = (JArray)obj["posts"];
        string writing = (string)array[0]["content"]; 
        return writing;
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
var jsonManager = new JsonDataManager("whatever");
var writing = await jsonManager.getWriting();
```

This code is not tested, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to post data and get json result, I suggest you to use **StreamReader** to get response properly. Please see below method, It will return result as string and you can parse it to json.

```
    public string GetJsonResult(string url, string queryStringValues)
    {
    // Create web request
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest;
    httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url + queryStringValues);
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.Timeout = 6000;
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

    System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

    // Make the request and get the response
    HttpWebResponse response = null;
    response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    string content = "";
    using (var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
    content = stream.ReadToEnd();
    }
    return content;
    }
```

Comment: no need streamreader but still httpwebrequest works well! with async and await